# old Fortran "shared" feature in open() causing open file failure

Tags: fortran, intel, intel-fortran

I am using a code which is written in very old Fortran language. There are some lines using the `shared` option in the `open()` routine. E.g.:

```
 OPEN(UNIT=17,STATUS='OLD',FORM='UNFORMATTED',READONLY,SHARED)
```

The compilation is ok. When running on one machine, it is ok. But later I moved to another machine, it gives the error:

> ```
>  forrtl: Function not implemented
>  forrtl: severe (30): open failure, unit 17, file
> ```

The compiler I use is the Linux version of intel Fortran 14.0.3 on both of the machine. When the `shared` feature is removed, everything is fine. But, since the code is not written by myself, I would like to keep it if possible. The reason of using this option is that I may the code on many threads at the same time. They may have to access some files at the same time.

- Do you have any idea of this?
- Is it safe to  just remove `shared` from the code?

Comment: Are you sure the error is for that line?  Your code is opening unit 10, but the runtime error is for unit 17.  Are the open calls the same for both units?

Comment: Hi casey, thanks for your reply. Actually, there are a bunch of this kind of opening file commands (of course, a lot error message ), but I just pick of of them randomly. Anyway, I modified the line to be consistent with the error message shown above.

Comment: You have said what is the same about the two systems but not what is different. The Intel compiler supports the SHARED argument but does the underlying operating system? First, if you have been using the same executable on both systems, try recompiling it on the second system and see if that resolves the problem. If it doesn't, look at what is different about the operating systems on the two machines. In particular, make sure file locking is supported on the second machine.

Comment: Hi froth, thank you very much for your answer. I was not using the same executables, but always compile the source code to get them. The main difference could be that the second machine is a cluster (HPC). To my knowledge, the file locking is enabled on both machines. Thanks again!