# Meaning of OPEN(..., SHARED) in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I'm porting a legacy Fortran console app to C# and encountered this statement:

```
    OPEN(UNIT=12,FILE = bufProgress,STATUS='UNKNOWN'
    1 ,SHARED,ERR = 9300)
```

(Indentation as-is.) What does `SHARED` mean in this context? (And it is part of the `OPEN` statement due to the `1` used for line continuation, right?)

Things I've found:

- There are no variables with this name in the entire program (comprising a single +7k-line file).
- This program was at one time compiled with "Digital Visual Fortran 6.0 Professional", a couple decades ago. I believe Intel's Fortran compiler has been used in the past decade, but am not sure.
- The file specified by the contents of buffer is (when the program is running as part of its "parent" multi-platform system) being written to by this console app and read from by another process.
- There is a commented-out statement just above this statement that looks like this:

  ```
  c   OPEN(UNIT=12,FILE='progress.tmp',STATUS='UNKNOWN'
  c   1 ,SHARE='DENYRD',ERR = 9300)
  ```

  It seems like `SHARE='DENYRD'` once had a similar semantic at one point?
- I've found nothing online regarding `SHARED` or `SHARE` in the context of `OPEN`.

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: Possible duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147048/old-fortran-shared-feature-in-open-causing-open-file-failure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245989/shared-option-in-open-statement-in-the-fortran-standard

Comment: Did you miss http://h41379.www4.hpe.com/doc/82final/6443/6443pro_023.html#sec_shared_file when searching online?

Comment: @VladimirF Unfortunately, none. I've tried gfortran on this listing via Code::Blocks, but I don't have access to the IMSL library that this program depended on when compiled in past years. gfortran emits lots of syntax errors. Would it help if I added these to the question?

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you for that hpe.com link, it looks promising! I did indeed miss it. I won't be able to review it thoroughly until later today though. I'll update as soon as I can.

Comment: you don't say if you actually have a problem, but note "Shared" is essentially the default on linux-ish systems. On windows you would typically need that option or some compiler flag to prevent file locking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best reference find-able for me:

Try this site for FORTRAN reference: https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-fortran-compiler-17.0-user-and-reference-guide

SHARED:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/678862

> The SHARED specifier indicates that the file is connected for shared
>   access by more than one program executing simultaneously.

appears to prevent record locking for performance and may not be used in current versions of FORTRAN.

For SHARE=[type]
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/678861

> 'DENYRD' Indicates deny-read mode. No process can open the file with
>   read access.

Other FORTRAN notes can be found at the Intel site.

Comment: As others have hinted, this syntax may date from the time before Fortran had a standard specification of equivalent functionality.  By default, an opened file would be locked by the opener so that other processes cannot access it, usually in order to prevent unexpected writes to the file.  You would need to translate it into standard syntax to work with a current compiler.

Comment: The Fortran standard doesn't include syntax to specify file sharing - SHARED and SHARE are extensions. Intel Fortran supports two different syntaxes for this as one is DEC heritage and one is Microsoft heritage. You may be able to just remove the option, though the behavior.then will be implementation and platform dependent.